# How do you echo content before the while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I’m trying to figure out how to echo out content above the while loop and underneath the check for num_rows, but I need to get the content from the while loop before doing that.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $test);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($stmt_result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<div id='wrapper'>"; //I need to add HTML content here if $status === 2
    while ($row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $title = $row['title'];
       $description = $row['descript'];
       $status = $row['status'];
       if ($status === 2) {
          echo $status;
          continue; //skip to the next iteration
       }
       echo $title;
       echo $description;
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm missing the obvious. How is it done?

To summarize, this is the output I'm looking for:

```
//if status !== 2: (i get 3 results)
<div id='wrapper'>
//title
//description

//title
//description

//title
//description
</div>
//if status === 2: (i get 1 result)
<div id='other_wrapper'>
//title
//description
</div>
//if status === 3: (i get 5 results)
<div id='yet_another_wrapper'>
//title
//description

//title
//description

//title
//description

//title
//description

//title
//description
</div>
```

Comment: You can't echo something that hasn't been loaded yet. You need to call that *after* `fetch_assoc` has retrieved the relevant data.

Comment: Maybe i'm using the wrong approach. Is there a way to get a row using the ```echo $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()['status]``` before the while loop? Using it together with the while loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you fetch and pluck out a single entry then it won't be available within the loop. Try fetching and saving to an array, then inspecting, echo as necessary, then loop again over the array.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this could work for you.

Put these lines in place of the while loop

```
$rows = $stmt_result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  if ($row['status'] === 2) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['descript'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    if ($status === 2) {
      echo $status;
      continue; //skip to the next iteration
    }
    echo $title;
    echo $description;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty brilliant, I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$idv =0;
if ($stmt_result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if($row['status'] ==2 && $idv==0){
     $idv =1;
     echo "<div id='wrapper'>"; //adds div once only if status is 2
   }
   $title = $row['title'];
   $description = $row['descript'];
   $status = $row['status'];
   if ($status === 2) {
      echo $status;
      continue; //skip to the next iteration
   }
   echo $title;
   echo $description;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also a good solution, plus it lets me keep the while loop. Give me a moment while i try the solutions

Answer (score 0):

The above answers a great, but someone provided the perfect solution:

```
$wrappers = [
   'wrapper' => [/* items from db with status not 2 or 3 */]
   'other_wrapper' => [/* items from db with status 2 */]
   'yet_another_wrapper' => [/* items from db with status 3 */]
];
function getWrapperNameForStatus($status) {
    if($status === 2) {
        return 'other_wrapper';
    }

    if($status === 3) {
        return 'yet_another_wrapper';
    }

    return 'wrapper';
}

$wrappers = [];
while ($row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $wrapperName = getWrapperNameForStatus($row['status']);

    $wrappers[$wrapperName][] = [
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'description' => $row['description'],
        'status' => $row['status']
    ];
}
```

Credit goes to https://www.phphelp.com/u/JimL for this solution. It's clean, gives you the ability to post unlimited content within unlimited wrappers, and it prevents code duplication. Thanks Jim.